# Installing libcudnn

Tags: tensorflow

7 hours (9:33 AM)
Good morning,

I had a question regarding the instructions of libcudnn for tensorflow in python. Ive put the folders and added the respective path and environment variables, but after that the instructions indicate to add something to the compiler and link lines. I really dont understand what does this mean. Could anyone give me some advice on how to do it or a reference where i could learn about the line concepts? I'd appreciate it.

LINUX

```
cd <installpath>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Add <installpath> to your build and link process by adding -I<installpath> to your compile
line and -L<installpath> -lcudnn to your link line.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a normal installation, it usually just works. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` tells tensorflow where the CUDA dynamic libraries are. If you installed them with-apt-get, or if you are using a nvidia-docker container, then there might nothing else for you to do.

If you installed bazel, then you should not have to tinker with compile flags. If you found that in current documentation, let us know and we can update the docs.

For installation issues, we are better equipped to answer questions on our github page, where you can have a longer-form submission and discussion: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues